# iOS 10 broke my decimal separators, any way to change them back?

Tags: ios

Since iOS 10, Apple has started using what I assume to be language-based settings for separators.

Until 9 it was using region-based settings for me.
I happen to prefer dots over commas but I don't really care about the appearance.

My problem is Apple doesn't enforce proper localization and my brokers(which are the apps I use the most) all happen to have broken locale functions that turn 1,000 shares into 1.000 shares and then interpret that as if it meant 1 point O shares.

I waited a few months but Apple seems to be applying no pressure on the infringing apps.

Separators appear as if they were something the user could possibly set in the Settings screen.

Is there any way to fix them without switching everything to US English?

**edit**: As of iOS11, the apps and/or iOS have been fixed. Still not able to choose the separators, though.

Comment: I'm surprised this still isn't fixed in iOS 12. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please have a look at Settings > General > Language & Region.

After "Preferred Language Order" you see a setting for "Region". Change it to your preferred setting.

If it is already set to your correct region setting, set it to another region and then back to your preferred region.

Let me know if this works for you.

edit:
Make sure to check the "Region Format Example" field. It displays how the decimal separator will look like.

Comment: Nah, I tried a few languages and regions and the language "appropriate" separator is always selected. Currencies are working properly.

Comment: How is the decimal separator displayed in the "Region Format Example" field? Also, which region to you want to set it to?

Comment: It's displayed as 1.235 JP¥ 4.567,89 for Japan whereas I want ¥1,235 4,567.89 . It's possible it was working by chance previously but all weird Euro-format languages are affected.

Answer (score -2):

Change country to Swiss or German and vice versa. Hope this helped.